# WCF client behavior for HTTP Status

Tags: wcf, rest

I need to access a RESTful server, which is not created with WCF. For that I'm using a `WebHttpBinding`, a `ChannelFactory<MyInterface>` and a `WebHttpBehavior`.

Most things are working like expected. However, the server offers various listings and sends a response with HTTP status of 404 which raises an exception. I'd prefere to not raise an exception as an empty list is not really an excetional condition here.

Note that I have no influence on the server, I'm just writing a client. I tried to add a custom Behavior to my factory, however the exception is raised before `AfterReceiveReply`

**Edit**

I also use OAuth and I dont want to to anything besides using WCF.

How can I influence WCFs behavior on different HTTP status?

Comment: What is the exact exception that is being raised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for restful services, you can use HttpWebRequest, and when reading the response stream you can handle the WebException.

simple and it works :D

Comment: sure, far small projects that's fine, but the api I have to work with that would lead to too much code. Also I have to use WPF as a requirement, that's why I included it in the question ;D

Comment: @Mene Mandating the use of WCF on the client to communicate with a "REST" server is simply crazy.  Using a HTTP client is the only sane approach.